# What flips are unnecessary in parkour/freerunning?

Tags: parkour

When people in parkour videos do flips, they look cool, but is it really important to do it? To what extent should you do a flip (i.e. heights, obstacles)?
Also, what flips should a beginner learn?

Answer (score 2):

All of them, and none of them.

You can't ask about both parkour and freerunning at the same time, since they are two different things.

In parkour, you aim to overcome an obstacle as fast as possible. Flips are almost always unnecessary, but they can be added for flair.

In freerunning, you aim to simply perform tricks, which makes flips very satisfying.

But at the end of the day, it is completely opinion-based.